# Geospatial One-Stop no longer accessible?

Tags: data, united-states

I was wondering what happened to the "Geospatial One-Stop" site?

The link:

http://www.geodata.gov

is no longer accessible.

Is the portal superseded by another government website, or is it abandoned?

Comment: https://www.data.gov/geospatial/ ?

Comment: Looks like that's been redirected to geo.data.gov or similar [since at least 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120101084636/http://geodata.gov/).

Answer (score 0):

It has been replaced by GeoPlatform (https://www.geoplatform.gov) and Data.gov